# Dplyr replace value based on function of previous column and row

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to replace NA values with the mean of the previous row and previous column same row using dplyr. See example below:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,1,2), 
                    B=c(2,4,NA))
```

So in this case the NA would be replaced by 3. How do I do this?

Below is what I was the lines I was thinking on but it doesn't work.

```
dfb <- df %>%
        mutate(B = if_else(is.na(B), mean(lag(B),A), B))
```

Thanks!

Comment: `mean` works vector wise (in a column), so it will take the mean of lag(B) and the mean of A and return a 2-element vector. You would need a `pmean` analogous to `pmax`. You could write your own implementation, or use the function from this package: https://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/WGCNA/html/pquantile.html

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `mean` we can mention them separately and then divide it by 2.

```
df %>% mutate(B = ifelse(is.na(B),(lag(B) + A)/2, B))

#  A B
#1 1 2
#2 1 4
#3 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple base R method using subsetting is

```
df$B[is.na(df$B)] <- (df$B[which(is.na(df$B))-1] + df$A[is.na(df$B)]) / 2
df
  A B
1 1 2
2 1 4
3 2 3
```

`is.na` returns a logical vector indicating whether each element is NA. `which` returns the position of logical TRUE elements. `which` is necessary for the first component of the average, since we have to find the lagged value.

This can be extended a bit to reduce computation (responding to docendo-discimus's comment) by computing the missing values once, and storing it, then re-using this vector.

```
missers <- is.na(df$B)
df$B[missers] <- (df$B[which(missers)-1] + df$A[missers]) / 2
#clean up, maybe
rm(missers)
```